# what is difference between project exe and project setup

Tags: .net, installation, exe

I want to know that why we need to create setup of the application? I know it is very silly question but i want to know it.

Because when we create new project in the .net then the debug folder of the project contains project exe then why should we need to create setup of the project.

Comment: Please don't say sorry for asking a question. We all here for learning.

Comment: @Soner Gönül : I think this is not good question & it might waste some important time of the people who answers. But ok i'll edit my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a setup project can be a good solution for a Windows application that has many dependencies on other assemblies / DLLs. The setup will figure out what the dependencies are for the application and automatically include them.

Note: This does not include the .NET framework.

Comment: @Priyanka - you require to add it something like this : http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/Add_framework_in_setup.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Well, if (and only if) your complete project consists of that one `exe` file, and never needs to be installed anywhere, and is supposed to be run by the same type of users who installs it, and has no dependencies at all, then you don't need setup.

The purpose of the setup is to *set up* the environment in which your project will run: check if the necessary prerequisites are met, check license, put the executable into some standard folder (e.g. somewhere in `%PROGRAMFILES%`), get the necessary configuration (most notably "for all users/only for this user"), set up shortcuts, and the uninstaller (which should be able to revert all that). Note also that various setup methods (e.g. `msi`) allow for managed installation, which may be somewhat useful when the site admin needs to install the program on 10K computers without logging into each one separately.

Answer (score 0):

before .net (vb 5.0,etc) it was quite hard install an application without a setup project: most of the application at the age were based on COM objects which need to be manually installed. In .net Microsoft has got rid of that of that making possible to do what is called "copy and past deploy"). That means what you are asking: In theory to deploy an application you just need to copy and past all the files(even if for someone it could be already enough difficult). Sometime you need to do some extra steps to makes your application work perhaps installing something in the GAC, creating a special folders,checking if the X software is installed, etc. In this scenario you would probability need a setup project to make the deploy process easier